# Querying Json whose root is an array of objects in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a column in SQL table that has json value like below:

```
[
  {"address":{"value":"A9"},
  "value":{"type":11,"value":"John"}}, 
  {"address":{"value":"A10"},
  "value":{"type":11,"value":"Doe"}}]
```

MSDN Examples for JSON_VALUE or JSON_QUERY require a json object at root. How can I query above to return rows that have "address" as A9 and "value" as John? I'm using SQL Azure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[
  {"address":{"value":"A9"},
  "value":{"type":11,"value":"John"}}, 
  {"address":{"value":"A10"},
  "value":{"type":11,"value":"Doe"}}]'



select a.*
from openjson(@json) r
cross apply openjson(r.value)
with (   
        address  nvarchar(200)   '$.address.value',  
        name     nvarchar(200)  '$.value.value'
     ) a  
where address = N'A9'
  and name = N'John'
```

outputs

```
address name
------- -----
A9      John

(1 row affected)
```

Comment: Thanks, In my case json is a column in SQL table.  Can openjson(@json) take a column name instead of variable? What is the perf penalty in using openjson compared to querying a json object directly using $. syntax?

Comment: I was able to use the column in openjson() like below. It will be great to know perf impact as my table can grow really large with 100s of million rows.  :  SELECT *
FROM [UserRecordData] P 

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (P.Data)
with (   
        address  nvarchar(200)   '$.address.value',  
        name     nvarchar(200)  '$.value.value'
     ) a  
  WHERE ISJSON(Data)>0
  AND address = 'A9'
  AND name = 'John'

Comment: I find it interesting that with such JSON it is possible to say `JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0]')` - this will return what appears to be the first element of the unnamed array. But then it does not seem possible to reference the keys within that element. e.g. It is not possible to say `JSON_VALUE('$[0].address.value')` - quite frustrating! It is possible, i.e. apparently valid, but always returns `NULL`

Comment: What if the JSON is a simple string array, `["a", "b", "c"]` ? I am not able to make this work: `select id from openjson(@json) r cross apply openjson(r.value) with (id varchar(10) '$') x;`. It errors saying "incorrect syntax near '$'." :-(

Comment: Very strange. Even the code snippet in the above answer throws the same error. "Incorrect syntax near '$.address.value'."

Comment: OK. Found that it is because SQL Server Compatibility being lower than 130. Ref: https://database.guide/openjson-incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-with-in-sql-server-solved/

Answer (score 0):

It may not be entirely relevant to the OP's post as the usage is different, however it is possible to retrieve arbitrary items from a root-level unnamed JSON array e.g.

```sql
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[
  {"address":
    {"value":"A9"},
   "value":
    {"type":11,"value":"John"}
  }, 
  {"address":
    {"value":"A10"},
   "value":
    {"type":11,"value":"Doe"}
  }
]'

select
    JSON_VALUE(
        JSON_QUERY(@json, '$[0]'),
        '$.address.value') as 'First address.value',
    JSON_VALUE(
        JSON_QUERY(@json, '$[1]'),
        '$.address.value') as 'Second address.value'
```

Output :

```
First address.value         Second address.value
A9                          A10
```